# Why isn't the element getting rendered even though there is no syntax error nor warning?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I have fetched the top 30 teams in CSGO from the Hltv API. The data is stored inside the `team` variable and I use a map function in order to get the individual teams names from the array and render it. However, it currently is not rendering anything.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HLTV from 'hltv';

function App() {

  const get = async () => {
    return await HLTV.getTeamRanking()
      .then(res => Object.entries(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  const teamNames = [];

  (async () => {
    const teams = await get();

    teams.map(x => {
      teamNames.push(x[1].team.name);
    });

    teamNames.map(team => {
      console.log(team);
    })
  })();

  return (
    <ul>
      {teamNames.map(team => <li>{team}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `teamNames` are empty at render time. You should make them a [state object](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to have the component automatically re-render when their value changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't know that the teamMates variable is being updated. In order to let React know about a change in the variable, you should either fetch the data before rendering the component or use `useState` with `useEffect`.

You can read the [useState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) for more information.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HLTV from 'hltv';

const get = async () => {
  return await HLTV.getTeamRanking()
    .then(res => Object.entries(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function App() {
  const [teamNames, setTeamNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    get().then(teams => {
      setTeamNames(teams.map(x => x[1].team.name));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {teamNames.map(team => <li>{team}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't render because the results arrive too late for the initial render. Change `teamNames` to be stateful, e.g. `const [teamNames, setTeamNames ] = useState([])`. Then update the incoming result with `setTeamNames`. And instead of an  IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), use `useEffect(() => {...})`.

For example:

```
function App() {

  const [teamNames, setTeamNames] = useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTeamRankings = async () => {
      return HLTV.getTeamRanking()
        .then(res => Object.entries(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };
      fetchTeamRankings().then(result => setTeamNames(result.map( r => r[1].team.name  )));
  }, [setTeamNames]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {teamNames.map(team => <li>{team}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```